# how to close a #elif statement in c?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I want to write #ifdef syntax in c

how should I write this?

```
#ifdef OP1
        foo1(categoryName);
#endif
#ifdef OP2
        foo2(categoryName);
#endif
```

is there neater way?

```
#ifdef OP1
        foo1(categoryName);
#elseif #ifdef OP2
        foo2(categoryName);
#endif
```

Comment: #if OP==1 #elif OP==2 #endif

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
#ifdef OP1
        foo1(categoryName);
#elif defined(OP2)
        foo2(categoryName);
#endif
```

For greater symmetry, you could start with:

```
#if defined(OP1)
```

But that's just a matter of taste.